# Crystal Reports edit axis labels option grayed out

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a report developed in Crystal Reports XI that includes a line graph.  In an early version of the report, I was able to edit my axis labels.  But I redid the report, and now the Edit Axis Labels option on my Chart menu is grayed out.  No matter what I do, it stays grayed out.  What can I do to enable that option?

Answer (score 0):

Under the Titles tab in Chart Options, there are field to enter the group axis label and the data axis label.  The group axis is the X axis and the data axis is the Y axis.  I've no idea why the "Edit Axis Labels" choice is there on the menu.  It does not appear to have a reason.